# Autofac register assembly types as closed types of

Tags: c#, autofac

The problem: I have to register multiple concrete implementations of generic base class using Autofac. Base class implements generic interface. But the trouble comes when one of the concrete implementations extends its constructor with additional parameters that base class does not have.

```
public interface IGenericHandler<in TModel, in TContext, TResult>
    where TModel : class
    where TContext : class
    where TResult : class
{
    Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync(TModel model, TContext context);
}

public abstract class HandlerBase<TModel> : IGenericHandler<TModel, ConcreteContext, ConcreteResult>
    where TModel : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext dbContext;
    protected readonly ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope;

    public HandlerBase(DbContext dbContext, ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    protected abstract Task<ConcreteResult> ExecuteAsync(TModel model, ConcreteContext);
}

public class ConcreteHandler1 : HandlerBase<ConcreteModel1>
{
    ConcreteHandler1(DbContext dbContext, ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) : base(dbContext, lifetimeScope)
    {
    }
    
    protected override async Task<ConcreteResult> ExecuteAsync(ConcreteModel1 model, ConcreteContext context)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
}

public class ConcreteHandler2 : HandlerBase<ConcreteModel2>
{
    private readonly IDependency dependency;

    ConcreteHandler2(IDependency dependency, DbContext dbContext, ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) : base(dbContext, lifetimeScope)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    protected override async Task<ConcreteResult> ExecuteAsync(ConcreteModel2 model, ConcreteContext context)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
}

public interface IDependency
{
}

public class Dependency : IDependency
{
}

// DI registration
public class HandlerModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);
        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>().As<IDependency>();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ConcreteHandler1).Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IGenericHandler<,,>));
    }
}
```

ConcreteHandlers are placed in the same folder while HandlerBase is in another and that is the reason why we are registering assembly type of the concrete one and not of the base handler.

Question is how to register ConcreteHandler2 while keeping the registration of the assembly types based on the generic interface?

Comment: You should explain what isn't working and what you've tried. Registering several implementations across multiple assemblies shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Resolver does not know how to deal with ConcreteHandler2 because it's dependent on additional IDependency parameter in the constructor, other concrete handler implementations are constructing instances using base constructor.

Comment: Like I said, you really need to explain what isn't working. Is there an exception? Where? What do you want to do to solve it? Are you asking how to register all the handlers _except certain ones_? [That's in the docs.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#filtering-types) You have some context here that others don't, which means you need to be a bit more explicit. For example, "ConcreteHandlers are placed in the same folder" - a folder is a filesystem construct; a _namespace_ is .NET. Are they all in the same assembly? Physical assemblies in the same folder?